# How to update product quantity after 'approved' status?

Tags: laravel

I have these tables:

products:

```
id - name - quantity - etc 
2    watch      4   
4    T-shirt    2
```

orders:

```
id - user_id - address_id - etc
```

pivot table between them called `order_product`

```
order_id - product_id - quantity
  1          2            3
  1          4            1
```

The relation:

```
/**
 * Products table relation
 */
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product')->withPivot('quantity');
}

 /**
 * Orders table relation
 */
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Order')->withPivot('quantity');
}
```

I need when I update the status to approved then update my quantity product!

My shut: ( Here I'm confused because the product can be many! the quantity as well )

```
public function status_orders(Order $order ,Request $request)
{

if($request->status == 'approved'){

  $product_quantity = $order->products->pluck('quantity');

   foreach($order->products as $order){
        $order_quantity = $order->pivot->quantity;
    }

    $final_quantity = $product_quantity - $order_quantity;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to update product table quantity after an order is approved. right?? you can do it the following way

```
public function status_orders(Order $order ,Request $request) {
    if($request->status == 'approved') {
        foreach($order->products as $product) {
            $product->update([
                'quantity' => $product->quantity - $product->pivot->quantity
            ]); 
        }
    }
}
```